# Condition to check if a backup ran successfully and start another one

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set a condition to a crontab script for backup to don't start another backup if the last one is not yet completed or if the script is still running, in case a backup will run slower or something like this. For this I created something similar but linux first is creating the process and than will execute the scripts commands so it will allways exist with "process is running":

```
ps auxw | grep backup.sh | grep -v grep > /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  echo "process is running"    
  exit 1
else
  ./backup.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code snippet comes from `backup.sh` file, then you can put the above verification into a separate file. Then grep will not match "itself".

Another way is using additional in-use files. Create the in-use file and - in case when the file exists - exit 1. Just make sure the in-use file is removed after the script finishes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit

trap cleanup ERR INT QUIT

cleanup()
{
    rm -f "$INUSE"
}

INUSE=/home/abc/inuse/backup.inuse

if [ if -f "$INUSE" ]; then
    echo "process is running"
    exit 1
else
    touch "$INUSE"
fi

# backup starts in here

# end of backup
cleanup
```